# UIAlertView text formatting

Tags: fonts, uitextview, uialertview

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to change the text formatting of the uialertview. i.e

The message "You have won" but with the "won" word in bold.

I looked around and it seems that the only solution is for me to create my own popup.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: UIAlertView, similar to a number of classes in iOS, is not directly modifiable.  UIActionSheet has some of the same shortcomings.  With iOS5 being released recently, many classes are more open, but I haven't heard of any changes to either of these.

Comment: Thanks for the info . I decided to create my own since it is only a view with some animation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible at present. You'd have to create a custom `UIAlertView`. That's the only option as it is not to be subclassed.

From the Class Reference:

> **Subclassing Notes**
>   The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
>   and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
>   private and must not be modified.

There are open source versions out there though. Have a search on "Custom UIAlertView" and you'll easy find them. For example see this question for some links:

[Custom UIAlertView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853124/custom-uialertview)