# Custom UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Seeing as the blue doesn't go with my UI interface, im just wondering if there is a way to change the colour of the uialertview, or use a image instead. With all the buttons, 'dismiss' etc still there

Thanks

Comment: you could present a modal/popover view maybe- just a thought? make it seem like an alert and make a dismiss button that dismisses it?

Comment: Would this work? It's still blue. https://github.com/kyoshikawa/ZPopoverController

Answer (score 20):

The fine folks at CodeCropper just put out an open-source control that lets you create custom alert views.  It's awesome.

[image]

https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

Comment: Problem with this project is that it uses ARC. You will get compile problems left and right if your project does not use ARC. I don't get why people use ARC?

Comment: @SamBudda: ARC is fantastic. Either way, if you don't use ARC you can explicitly enable it per-file on the build phases tab in Xcode. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523816/456851

Comment: @SamBudda, do you enjoy explicityly `retain/release`ing your objects?

Answer (score 1):

You could try presenting a Modal View Controller with a transparent background.

```
    ModalViewController *popupController = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil]; 
[self presentModalViewController:popupController animated:NO];
```

Something like this for the ModalView (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849458/transparent-modal-view-on-navigation-controller)

This way you can create a custom Alert, but it's really a modal view that you can customize

Comment: FYI watch out with this approach- presenting a view controller modally, even with a transparent background, will make the view behind it disappear, leaving a white background.  It will probably not be the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go through its subviews and change what you need to change, or subclass it. Because UIAlertView inherits from UIView you can use:

```
 myAlertView.subViews
```

and modify the views or subclass UIAlertView to create your custom AlertView. Here is a very good article on how to sublass UIAlertView to get whatever design/color you want.

[Subclassing UIAlertView](http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert)

Basically what you want to override is this method:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a uiview instead of uialertview and can easily customize uiview according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CODialog](https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog). It's fully style-able and configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing UIAlertView is not an option, this class is not intended to be subclassed and doing so might be a reason of app rejection.

Instead, you might try to go through all alert view's subviews or create your own class

In case you are going to create your own class, here's an example of how to fake UIAlertView:

http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.com/2013/04/creating-custom-alert-view-for-iphone.html

Comment: you are right, here's a quote from Apple "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified." 
So creating new class with similar functionality seems to be the only option

Answer (score 0):

If looking for **custom alert** view then it might help.

```
https://github.com/Pradeepkn/PKCustomAlertView/
```

Hope it helps some one.

No need of setting **delegate**. You will get **call back** once the action completes on same method. 
Enjoy :)

[Custom Alert view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxXiy.png)

[Table Alert view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgolK.png)