# How to enable ARC for a single file

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I want to bring a single Objective-C class written using ARC into an old project. The internet provides many references for how to enable ARC for your project and then disable it for single files but I want to do the opposite.

I want to leave the project as it is, i.e. using manual reference counting, and then enable ARC just for the new file. (My searches have failed me here.)

Is this possible? How?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate! It's asks the opposite of the linked question. The linked question does not provide the answer. The title of this question comes up as a Google suggestion for which there is no obvious page. @Caleb's answer is the perfect one.

Comment: I have to agree with you there... the linked supposed duplicate thread doesn't mention "-fobjc-arc" once.  The people who marked this as a duplicate should be shot out of a giant cannon into the sun.

Comment: The problem linked as a duplicate isn't the correct one. However, this one is and was written earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768176/how-to-add-arc-for-specific-file

Comment: Note that when you do a do a Google search, this is the question that comes up first.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Add the `-fobjc-arc` flag to any files for which you'd like to enable ARC, as described in the [ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general).

Comment: Thanks Caleb — exactly what was missing from every other page, bar the manual of course :-) thanks for that link.

Answer (score 13):

Select `Target > Build Phases >  Compile Source > Select Your class > Double Click`> Type

`-fobjc-arc` in dialog box 
[image]

Enter.