# Need example of a left slide-out menu that doesn't use ARC (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am updating an older massive project (circa 2010) that is NOT using ARC. All the examples I have found use ARC. Xcode will convert the project to use ARC but after the conversion, I have about 300+ red errors. With that in mind, it is easier to keep the project the way it is and add a slide out menu without using ARC. i just need an example to pull from. Thanks

Comment: Believe me, it's worth it to take the time to complete the migration by resolving the errors

Comment: While your question is off-topic, please note that just because your project is not using ARC does not mean that you can't use a library or other code that does use ARC. It's easy to mix and match ARC and MRC code in one project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523816/how-to-enable-arc-for-a-single-file for how to enable arc for individual files

Comment: what about the compiler flags (`-fobjc-arc`) for the ARC files in a MRR project...? by the way, converting the project to ARC by removing the `release`, `autorelese`, `retain` keywords at 300 times would take about an hour extra job at most, it must not take longer as it sounds your project is quite tiny.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to simply find example you want and follow old memory management rules (retain-release) to convert ARC code to not ARC. if you have problems with understanding how to use MMR (manual memory management) i recommend you to read tutorials. For example you can read that: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/memory-management

Comment: There is no reason to convert ARC code to MRC code. You can use both as needed.