# Compiler error: cannot create __weak static in file using manual reference

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have recently purchased an app and while trying to make edits in Xcode, I am getting a compiler error with the error saying:

> cannot create __weak static in file using manual reference

[image: Snippet of code]

Comment: Please consider adding code as text with appropriate formatting to your question instead of providing a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you are not using ARC in that file and so you cannot use `weak`, `strong` and so on. Therefore you have to remove the keyword `__weak`.

Comment: Thanks for that, again i am new to Objective C, how can I add ARC into the file in order to let me use the keywords

Comment: This shows you how add arc to a single file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32664413/5109911 , If my answer fix your problem please mark as right and then you can rise other questions if you don't find the solution by yourself

Comment: Thanks again Marco, where do I find the Target> Build Phases> in Xcode?

Comment: @DanAshby https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/EditingBasicSettings.html